# Combine Rows into columns sql

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to query a database as to list the trainer plans in a list or is this something that we should do within Visual Basic

I've been told to do this with sql and/or visual basic, I've tried to go with some wierd for and foreach or while loops but not gotten very far. From the project we should use pure c# or sql nothing more.

I’ve currently created a SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    Trainers.ID, Trainers.FirstName, Trainers.LastName, Trainers.Phone, 
    Trainers.Hours, TrainerPlan.PlanID
FROM 
    FitnessPlans 
INNER JOIN 
    (Trainers INNER JOIN TrainerPlan ON Trainers.ID = TrainerPlan.TrainerID) ON FitnessPlans.ID = TrainerPlan.PlanID;
```

Which has a list of the trainers that results in this:

```
 ID FirstName  LastName Phone           Hours             PlanID
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 1  Calvin     Hodges   765-495-1234    MWF: 8 am - 4 pm    1
 1  Calvin     Hodges   765-495-1234    MWF: 8 am - 4 pm    2
 1  Calvin     Hodges   765-495-1234    MWF: 8 am - 4 pm    3
 1  Calvin     Hodges   765-495-1234    MWF: 8 am - 4 pm    4
 1  Calvin     Hodges   765-495-1234    MWF: 8 am - 4 pm    5
 1  Calvin     Hodges   765-495-1234    MWF: 8 am - 4 pm    6
 1  Calvin     Hodges   765-495-1234    MWF: 8 am - 4 pm    7
 1  Calvin     Hodges   765-495-1234    MWF: 8 am - 4 pm    8
 2  Brittany   Saxony   765-495-9876    TH: 8 am - 4 pm 3
 2  Brittany   Saxony   765-495-9876    TH: 8 am - 4 pm 5
 2  Brittany   Saxony   765-495-9876    TH: 8 am - 4 pm 6
 2  Brittany   Saxony   765-495-9876    TH: 8 am - 4 pm 7
 2  Brittany   Saxony   765-495-9876    TH: 8 am - 4 pm 8
 3  Jacob      Golden   765-495-1111    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 1
 3  Jacob      Golden   765-495-1111    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 2
 3  Jacob      Golden   765-495-1111    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 3
 3  Jacob      Golden   765-495-1111    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 4
 3  Jacob      Golden   765-495-1111    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 5
 3  Jacob      Golden   765-495-1111    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 6
 4  Lisa       Harris   765-494-0987    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 3
 4  Lisa       Harris   765-494-0987    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 5
 4  Lisa       Harris   765-494-0987    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 6
 4  Lisa       Harris   765-494-0987    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 7
 4  Lisa       Harris   765-494-0987    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 8
```

It’s supposed to look like this:

```
  1 Calvin  Hodges  765-495-1234    MWF: 8 am - 4 pm    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
  2 Brittany    Saxony  765-495-9876    TH: 8 am - 4 pm 3,5,6,7,8
  3 Jacob   Golden  765-495-1111    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 1,2,3,4,5,6
  4 Lisa    Harris  765-494-0987    MTWHF: 4 pm - 12 am 3,5,6,7,8
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pivot table,[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query)

for you

Answer (score 0):

Although Anand has suggested a pivot table which is typically associated with aggregate funcsions (sum, min, max, avg, etc), I don't believe it works for doing what MySQL allows as a "Group_Concat()" functionality..

However, I DID find a solution [from this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53/tsql-equivalent-for-groupconcat-function?forum=transactsql) that should work for you...   Modified to fit your needs though.

```
SELECT 
      T.ID, 
      T.FirstName, 
      T.LastName, 
      T.Phone, 
      T.Hours, 
      PreQueryPlans.AllPlans
   from
      ( select 
              TP.TrainerID, 
              stuff( (  select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + str(TP2.PlanID,3)
                           from TrainerPlan TP2
                           WHERE TP.TrainerID = TP2.TrainerID
                           order by TP2.PlanID
                           for xml path('') ), 1, 1, '') AS AllPlans
           from 
              TrainerPlan TP
           group by 
              TP.TrainerID ) PreQryPlans
      JOIN Trainers T
         on PreQryPlans.TrainerID = T.ID
```

Comment: @Wilken, ok, but what error... did I have a type-o, or bad column reference?